# Querying the "name" attribute of a nix program

Tags: nix

Let's say I using a nix program `nixProgram` which is located in some nix store location like

```
/nix/store/5zlrw36bpq6z1m3zjawwrwaryhmqjwbr-nixProgram-75.0/bin/nixProgram
```

Here I'm assuming `nixProgram-75.0` is the `name` attribute of the derivation.

**Question:** Is there some well-known way to query what the `name` attribute of the `nixProgram` is over the Linux shell? Something like

```
$ nix-get-name nixProgram
nixProgram-75.0
```

?

Comment: What do you want to use it for? `name` is generally not used or not recommended to be used, except in `nix-env --uninstall` which doesn't have an attribute-based alternative.

Comment: I have a nix package in which someone jammed the version into the `name` attribute, and I'm writing a shell script which checks that a nix package with certain version is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nix-store -qd` to get the derivation that generated the store path.  This derivation might have already been garbage collected in which case you're out of luck.  Otherwise you can use `nix show-derivation` to serialize the derivation to JSON and use `jq` to get the `name` field.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

die() {
    >&2 echo "$@"
    exit 1
}

# Get the store path of $1
STORE_PATH=${1%*${1#/nix/store/*/}}

# Query the derivation which generates the store path
DRV=$(nix-store -qd "$STORE_PATH")

# Check if the derivation is still there
[ -f "$DRV" ] || die "You're out of luck, the derivation is no longer there"

# Serialize to JSON and use jq to get the name
nix show-derivation "$DRV" | jq -r '.[] | .env.name'
```

On my system:

```
$ ./nix-get-name /nix/store/4xb9z8vvk3fk2ciwqh53hzp72d0hx1da-bash-interactive-4.4-p23/bin/bash
bash-interactive-4.4-p23
```